# Bash JSON compare two list and delete id

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have a JSON endpoint which I can fetch value with curl and yml local file. I want to get the difference and delete it with id of name present on JSON endpoint.

JSON's endpoint

```
[
  {
    "hosts": [
      "server1"
    ],
    "id": "qz9o847b-f07c-49d1-b1fa-e5ed0b2f0519",
    "name": "V1_toto_a"
  },
  {
    "hosts": [
      "server2"
    ],
    "id": "a6aa847b-f07c-49d1-b1fa-e5ed0b2f0519",
    "name": "V1_tata_b"
  },
  {
    "hosts": [
      "server3"
    ],
    "id": "a6d9ee7b-f07c-49d1-b1fa-e5ed0b2f0519",
    "name": "V1_titi_c"
  }
]
```

files.yml

```
---
instance:
  toto:
    name: "toto"
  tata:
    name: "tata"
```

Between JSON's endpoint and local file, I want to delete it with id of tata, because it is the difference between the sources.

```
declare -a arr=(_a _b _c)
ar=$(cat files.yml | grep name | cut -d '"' -f2 | tr "\n" " ")
fileItemArray=($ar)
ARR_PRE=("${fileItemArray[@]/#/V1_}")
for i in "${arr[@]}"; do local_var+=("${ARR_PRE[@]/%/$i}"); done
remote_var=$(curl -sX GET "XXXX" | jq -r '.[].name | @sh' | tr -d \'\")
diff_=$(echo ${local_var[@]} ${remote_var[@]} | tr ' ' '\n' | sort | uniq -u)
```

output = titi

the code works, but I want to delete the titi with id dynamically

curl -X DELETE "XXXX" $id_titi

I am trying to delete with bash script, but I have no idea to continue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your endpoint is **not** proper JSON as it has

- commas after the `.name` field but no following field
- no commas between the elements of the top-level array

If this is not just a typo from pasting your example into this question, then you'd need to address this first before proceeding. This is how it should look like:

```json
[
  {
    "hosts": [
      "server1"
    ],
    "id": "qz9o847b-f07c-49d1-b1fa-e5ed0b2f0519",
    "name": "toto"
  },
  {
    "hosts": [
      "server2"
    ],
    "id": "a6aa847b-f07c-49d1-b1fa-e5ed0b2f0519",
    "name": "tata"
  },
  {
    "hosts": [
      "server3"
    ],
    "id": "a6d9ee7b-f07c-49d1-b1fa-e5ed0b2f0519",
    "name": "titi"
  }
]
```

If your endpoint **is** proper JSON, try the following. It extracts the names from your .yml file (just as you do - there are plenty of more efficient and less error-prone ways but I'm trying to adapt your approach as much as possible) but instead of a Bash array generates a JSON array using `jq` which for Bash is a simple string. For your `curl` output it's basically the same thing, extracting a (JSON) array of names into a Bash string. Note that in both cases I use quotes `<var>="$(…)"` to capture strings that may include spaces (although I also use the `-c` option for `jq` to compact it's output to a single line). For the difference between the two, everything is taken over by `jq` as it can easily be fed with the JSON arrays as variables, perform the subtraction and output in your preferred format:

```sh
fromyml="$(cat files.yml | grep name | cut -d '"' -f2 | jq -Rnc '[inputs]')"
fromcurl="$(curl -sX GET "XXXX" | jq -c 'map(.name)')"
diff="$(jq -nr --argjson fromyml "$fromyml" --argjson fromcurl "$fromcurl" '
  $fromcurl - $fromyml | .[]
')"
```

The Bash variable `diff` now contains a list of names only present in the curl output (`$fromcurl - $fromyml`), one per line (if, other than in your example, there happens to be more than one). If the curl output had duplicates, they will still be included (use `$fromcurl - $fromyml | unique | .[]` to get rid of them):

```
titi
```

As you can see, this solution has three calls to `jq`. I'll leave it to you to further reduce that number as it fits your general workflow (basically, it can be put together into one).

Comment: thanks for your replying, but I edit the question because I add some manipulation string on array. Finally, I want to delete the titi instance with id.

Comment: That edit changes the overall workflow design a lot as you need to carry the according ids together with the names in order to filter by one and eventually output the other. Sure, given the current output of name(s) only, you could also use that to query for their id(s) in the contents of curl's output with yet another jq call, but a redesign would be the much preferred way to go from here imo.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the output of a program into a variable can be done using `read`.

```sh
perl -M5.010 -MYAML -MJSON::PP -e'
   sub get_next_file { local $/; "".<> }
   my %filter = map { $_->{name} => 1 } values %{ Load(get_next_file)->{instance} };
   say for grep !$filter{$_}, map $_->{name}, @{ decode_json(get_next_file) };
' b.yaml a.json |
while IFS= read -r id; do
   curl -X DELETE ..."$id"...
done
```

I used Perl here because what you had was no way to parse a YAML file. The snippet requires having installed the YAML Perl module.

Comment: thanks for your replying, but I edit the question because I add some manipulation string on array. Finally, I want to delete the titi instance with id.

Comment: I think you're saying you want `titi` in a script var? Use `read`. See update.

Comment: no, I want to get the id of titi, like that i can delete it

Comment: What do you mean? Your questions shows you want to build a `curl` request using the id, and my answer shows how to do that. Replace `printf 'Do something with %s\n' "$id"` with the appropriate `curl` command.